# Cannot install Ubuntu on Acer Aspire 3 - "watchdog: BUG: soft lockup: - CPU#1 stuck for 22s! [migration/1:15]"

Tags: system-installation, acer

I am trying to install Ubuntu Mate on my Acer Aspire 3, with AMD Ryzen 3 2200U and AMD Radeon Vega 3 Graphics, currently running Windows 10. 
When I boot from a USB and select **Install Ubuntu MATE** I am getting the following error:

[image: photo of screen with many soft lockup and other messages]

After that I disabled AMD-SVM and AMD-IOMMU in the BIOS menu, which cleared the first several lines of errors, but I still get some errors and cannot install Ubuntu

[image: photo of screen with manysoft lockup messages]

Can anyone help me out with this annoying issue? 
I contacted Acer support as well, but they said they cannot help since this is regarding an OS other than Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the BIOS? Annoyingly, this is something that usually needs Windows.

What version of Ubuntu MATE? 18.04 or 18.10?

Depending on what's on your startup disk, you may have hit the problem that the Ryzen APUs are new and only recent kernels know enough about them to run properly.

#### Step one

Edit the boot command line to have...

```
acpi=off
```

or if that doesn't work

```
pci=noacpi
```

before `quiet nosplash`. This should allow it to boot.

#### Step two

Get a later kernel, either via updates or by downloading one from the Ubuntu mainline repository.

(Disclaimer: I am on stage one at the moment - the laptop is dumping the contents of its Windows partition before I replace them with Ubuntu MATE...)

For some reason, after installing the 1.09 BIOS (it came with 1.03...) having `acpi=off` wouldn't allow it to boot. What did was having `pci=noacpi` there instead.

That allowed me to boot with the Ubuntu MATE 18.10 startup, install it alongside Windows, boot to GRUB, edit the command line to have `pci=noacpi`, and boot successfully.

I've edited `/etc/default/grub` to add that parameter to the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`, then run `sudo update-grub`, so I no longer have to edit the command line by hand each time.

So far, it's working...

The only other thing I have needed to do is turn off the advanced setting for the touchpad in the BIOS, because it wasn't working in Ubuntu MATE until I did that.

[This article may be helpful](https://www.cnx-software.com/2018/08/19/acer-aspire-3-a315-41g-amd-ryzen-7-2700u-laptop-ubuntu-18-04-m-2-ssd/)

Comment: Can you have another look and clarify this answer a bit? You have step one and step two but when and how did you update the BIOS (or rather, UEFI)? You're also assuming a lot of knowledge on OP's part, for example how to install a kernel, adding a boot parameter at startup. These things are not at all obvious to beginners struggling to install Ubuntu for the first time. OP might not be in that situation, but other readers will...

Comment: @Zanna to update/modify the boot options: on the GRUB ui (the one you select the way you wanna boot linux) press the "e" key and you'll see the boot options then on the row that says "linux"  edit the line adding the above options before the text that reads `quiet nosplash`